# C#: Changing code from Session to ViewState causing page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, viewstate, page-lifecycle

I have a page that contain some UserControls. Theses UC have some contents that are visible or not depending on where you click. 
This page was using Sessions to retain data from database, like this:

```
private ViewPersonCollection collection
    {
        get
        {
            if (Session["ViewPersonCollection.test1"] == null)
                Session["ViewPersonCollection.test1"] = new ViewPersonCollection ();
            return (ViewPersonCollection )Session["ViewPersonCollection.test1"];
        }
        set { Session["ViewPersonCollection.test1"] = value; }
    }
```

Since I was having some problems with session when clients were using different tabs at same browser, I changed it to view state, like this:

```
private ViewPersonCollection collection
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["ViewPersonCollection.test1"] == null)
                ViewState["ViewPersonCollection.test1"] = new ViewPersonCollection ();
            return (ViewPersonCollection )ViewState["ViewPersonCollection.test1"];
        }
        set { ViewState["ViewPersonCollection.test1"] = value; }
    }
```

but after this change, my page stopped loading the UserControls. If I click on a button, the page gets reloaded. I debugged it and the code is running ok, but for some reason the main page is being reloaded.

What could be doing it?

Comment: Click on view source, and see what size of viewState do you have, Storing big objects in the view state is not a best practice, as viewstate are simple hidden fields, and the html file's size becomes huge

Answer (score 0):

Each User Control uses its own ViewState that later is merged with the page ViewState. Anyways, ViewState isn't a good option for big objects.

You can try using this.Context.Item collection that it will be shared between your User Controls and your Page, but it will only hold the information in the same HTTP Request.